# Too low space, Cannot log in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, login, bleachbit

My system got shutdown while BleachBit running, due to low battery and now i cannot log in.When i log in into Guest account it shows '0 Bytes remaining'.Help me to solve this.

Comment: Please open the terminal (ctrl+Alt+F1), log in and perform `df -m`. Paste here the result.

Comment: sda1 100%used, /home/user/.private 100% used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a termimal from control alt f1, log in, if that is not possible boot a live dvd, mount your disk.

And start removing files until you get to a root with 95% full or less. Be careful to not delete system files and stick to files you are sure you can remove. Focus on removing bleachbit and files it created.

`du -H`  will show your current disk usage so you can check how much space you have.

Comment: sda1 100%used, /home/user/.Private 100% used

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using a very old version of BleachBit (like version 1.0), which is the latest in the Ubuntu 14.04 repositories.  If so, when you log in to Ubuntu (using the rescue mode already discussed), look under ~ for a folder with a randomly generated name.  Delete the folder with a command like "rm -rf (foldername)"

[BleachBit version 1.2](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/news/bleachbit-12) added fixes to both prevent this kind of problem and to make it easier to clean up.  If you are using BleachBit 1.2 or later, you can just delete the ~/.cache folder.

In the future be sure to update BleachBit from the [BleachBit web site](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/) because Ubuntu only ships updates of BleachBit with new releases of Ubuntu, and they also disable update notifications.